# Automatically format certain words in cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have cells containing some text:

- This is a text in a cell. This cell contains two sentences.
- This is also a cell. I have two cells in total.

I want to automatically make all the occurrences of `cell` to be bold:

- This is a text in a **cell**. This **cell** contains two sentences.
- This is also a **cell**. I have two cells in total.

Is this possible ?

Comment: I don't see a path to word/substring level font weight in sheets. Seems all based on range.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontweightfontweight

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible to automatically format certain words in cell values.

There is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6000) on the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker. Please star it to tell Google that we want this feature.